# I imported some librabries and i started gettings these errors

Tags: android, android-studio

Below are the libraries i imported

compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
  implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

Comment: Start by reading the errors.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to stackoverflow, it would help if you shared the error messages you are receiving as part of your question so those who can help have more information to use.

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem.
You are using

```
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
```

and

```
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
```

You can't use **compile** and **implementations** at the same time.

If you are using Android Studio 3.0+ use **implementations**
otherwise **compile**.